# How to get the value of an id and that it serves to delete an element from firebase realtime database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

It is the first time I use firebase and javascript, I am making a table where it shows me the data from a database in real time. For this, I'm pulling the data like this:

```js
function getSonido() {
  var firebase = "https://iotplatform-11dca-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/users/awsBewgkSMcqiINzOoFUiUe9D6r1/data_widget/sensor/sonido.json";
  var sensores = new EventSource(firebase);
  sensores.addEventListener('put', function(e) {
    var json = JSON.parse(e.data);
    console.log(json);
    if (json.path == "/") {
      tbody = document.getElementById("tbody_sonido");
      for (var key in json.data) {
        var tr = document.createElement("tr");
        var td_sensor = document.createElement("td");
        var td_sonido = document.createElement("td");
        var input_sonido = document.createElement("input");
        var td_ruta = document.createElement("td");
        var td_button = document.createElement("td");

        input_sonido.type = "number";
        input_sonido.id = key;
        input_sonido.readOnly = true;
        input_sonido.disabled = true;
        td_sensor.innerHTML = json.data[key].name;
        td_ruta.innerHTML = "/" + key + "/sonido";
        td_button.innerHTML = '<button class="btn btn-danger delete" id="' + key + '" type="button">Borrar</button>';

        td_sonido.appendChild(input_sonido);
        tr.appendChild(td_sensor);
        tr.appendChild(td_sonido);
        tr.appendChild(td_ruta);
        tr.appendChild(td_button);
        tbody.appendChild(tr);

        document.getElementById(key).value = json.data[key].sonido;
      }
    } else {
      s = json.path.split("/");
      console.log(s[1]);
      console.log(json.data);
      document.getElementById(s[1]).value = json.data;
    }
  });
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Widgets</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/get_sensores.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>Sound sensors</h1>
  <table id="table_sonido" class="table table-striped">
    <thead id="thead_sonido">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th>Route</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody_sonido">
      <!-- One row will be added for each item in the json file -->
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script>
    document.onload = getSonido();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Place a button on each item in the table that is added, all buttons have the same class but the ID value of each button will depend on the item saved in firebase, in console the button is displayed like this
[image]

I am trying to remove the element that I click to delete, for that I must get the value of the ID of the button, investigating found that I could use `console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("delete")[0].id);` but there I am specifying which button I want to get the value from, which is not correct.
Looking for I saw that some used the jQuery library but don't explain much the process.
While I found a solution to that first problem, I was working with the way to eliminate the element, in the documentation comes something like this `curl -X DELETE \ 'https://[PROJECT_ID].firebaseio.com/locations.json'` so try using something like this:

```js
const request = new Request('https://iotplatform-11dca-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/users/awsBewgkSMcqiINzOoFUiUe9D6r1/data_widget/sensor/sonido/0x459ece7.json', { method: 'DELETE'})
const response = await fetch(request)
return await response.json()
```

This would run with an onclick within a function but it also does nothing, try the same using the SDK, perform the configuration and use remove(), to remove but I also did not work and it marked me error or simply did not run.
I hope I have explained and I know that it is very extensive but I have already been several days and I have looked a lot for how to do this firebase even in videos but I just do not get the result I need and I have been trying everything for several days but I simply can not make it work.
I hope you can help me